# What would cause an error to have no message in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So this question is based more on why only part of an error is showing that the error itself (although it would be great if someone could also solve the error as well).

However, I have a logging function in Laravel that emails an error notification as well as logs it. (Admittedly, it's probably not the best practice, although it tends to serve its purpose). My code for sending the error email is as shown below...

**Exceptions\Handler.php**

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    \Mail::send('emails.error', ['error' => $e], function ($m) use ($e) {


        $m->from('noreply@mydomain.com', 'MMC API | Laravel Error ');

        $m->to('me@mydomain.com')
        ->cc('someoneelse@mydomain.com')
        ->subject($e->getMessage());
    });

    parent::report($e);
}
```

**resources\views\emails\error.blade.php**

```
<p><strong>Message: </strong>{{ $error->getMessage() }}</p>
<p><strong>File: </strong>{{ $error->getFile() }}</p>
<p><strong>Trace: </strong>{{$error->getTraceAsString()}}</p>
```

However, I just recieved and error without the Message from the `getMessage()` section of the email (as shown below)...

```
Message: 
File: C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php
Trace: 
    #0 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(823): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #1 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(691): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #2 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #3 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #5 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #6 C:\api\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(34): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #7 [internal function]: Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) 
    #8 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
    #9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #10 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #11 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) 
    #13 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
    #14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #15 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #17 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #18 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure)) 
    #19 C:\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #20 C:\api\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) 
    #21 {main}
```

It seems like there might have possibly been something wrong with the `Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors-` which I use to enable a cross-domain API or possibly a web crawler trying to poke around a different route than what I allow.

**For my original question though:** is it possible to have an error without a Message by which I could get it with `getMessage()`

**And bonus question:** is it possible to diagnose the Route error I'm getting with the limited information I have available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your original question is yes, you can have an Exception that does not have a message.

The answer to your bonus question is yes, you can get an educated guess based on the current information. When you do this, this actually shows you the answer to your original question.

From the stacktrace, it shows that the last method called (from line #0) was `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match`. If you go into [the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L131-L162) and look at this method, you can see that, if no route is matched, it calls `throw new NotFoundHttpException;`.

Given that this is the only Exception explicitly thrown by this method, as well as the fact that it is thrown without setting a message, it is a pretty good guess that this is your error.

So, basically, someone attempted to go to a route that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this kind of error before but not for mailing. But I can tell you that the error is from your Route its either you are trying to access a Route method that does not exist or you are using the wrong Route method